How does Chakotay know about the mirror universe?
In the Star Trek: Prodigy season two episode, "Cracked Mirror," sections of Voyager-A are shifted into different universes (similar to the Star Trek: Voyager episode, "Shattered," in which different sections of the ship were shifted into different time periods).
The main cast from season one, plus Chakotay, are ascending toward the bridge and find themselves in a different universe on every deck they pass through. On one deck, they are in the mirror universe and Chakotay says:

The mirror universe. I know this one. Be careful.

I don't remember any episode of Star Trek: Voyager set in the mirror universe.
How does Chakotay know about the mirror universe?

Related: Is the Mirror Universe the same one across all Star Trek shows?. Everyone who's been through training would likely have been well briefed.

Something like that would be well documented and known amongst officers in the Federation incase it happened again.

Non-canon but you board a mirror universe ship in Star Trek Voyager: Elite Force

Chakotay's dialogue within the episode itself indicates that his knowledge of the mirror universe is based on reports submitted by other Starfleet officers who'd been there.

GWYNDALA: What nightmare are we in now?
CHAKOTAY: The mirror universe. This is the last dimension I wanted to visit.
JANKOM POG: You know this place?
CHAKOTAY: Starfleet's had run-ins with the mirror universe before... and it's always bad news.
Star Trek: Prodigy - S02E14 - "Cracked Mirror"

Bashir learned of the existence of the mirror universe while attending Starfleet Academy.

BASHIR: Learning a new trade. Do you have any idea what happened?
KIRA: Have you ever heard of a Starfleet Captain named James Kirk?
BASHIR: Kirk? Of course. The transporter accident. Read about it at the Academy. So that's where we are.
KIRA: That's where we are.
Star Trek: Deep Space Nine - S02E23 - "Crossover"

